# vscode - load snippets based on react vs react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, visual-studio-code, code-snippets

Is there any way to load separate sets of snippets depending on if I'm developing, **for example,** a react project vs. a react native project?

Basically, when I hit my keybinding `(ctrl+shift+b)`, it should fill out my `Button` snippet, which is different for each:

react: `"<button className=''>$1</button>",`

react-native: `"<Button title='$1' onPress={()=>{}}/>",`

Right now I have a silly workaround where I use `.jsx` for web components and `.js` for react-native components, then configure my snippets for each language-mode accordingly, but I would prefer to use `.jsx` for both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This explanation regards to all file types/snippets, the examples are
>   of adding `react` snippets.

In VSCode, snippets are loaded according to file association. You can check the current file association on the bottom bar.

> Example for `JavaScript React` file: 
>   [image: enter image descriptionhere]

Now you need to configure the snippet to the desired file type, for this you need to add `files.associations` property in `settings.json`.

> File -> Preferences -> Settings -> Open Settings (JSON)

```
  "files.associations": {
    "*.react.js": "javascriptreact",
    "*.stories.js": "javascriptreact",
    "*.action.js": "javascriptreact",
    "*.reducer.js": "javascriptreact",
    "*.styles.js": "javascriptreact",
    "*.jsx": "javascriptreact",
    "*.js": "javascript"
  }
```

From this point, files names like `MyComponent.react.js` will associate with `javascriptreact` type.

All is left adding your snippets to `javascriptreact` type:

> View -> Command Palette -> Preference: Configure User Snippets

and choose a file type (if exists like `javascriptreact.json` or create a new file type like `javascriptreactnative`).

All snippets in the chosen type will associate and auto-suggests.

For example, the next snippet in `javascriptreact.json` will work only in `React` files as configured above:

```
  "React Fragment": {
    "prefix": "<>",
    "body": [
      "<>",
      "$1",
      "</>"
    ],
    "description": "Insert React Fragment"
  }
```

In conclusion, you need to separate `.jsx` extension to recognize `react` and `react-native`, for example: `*.native.jsx`

Comment: Okay, thanks for the thorough answer Dennis!  

So if I'm understanding this right, there is no way to have snippets in a file with the exact same name (MyComponent.jsx) behave differently based on whether it is a react or a react native project?  

It can only be achieved by naming my react files and my react native files differently (beit through file extensions or some sort of file tail)?

Comment: Yes, like `*.native.jsx` for `react-native` files, its a good practice to use extensions like this for a clue of what the files hold.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time!  Learned a lot from your file associations example :D